# ESP32C3 GPIO wake up from deep sleep

Tags: c++, c, embedded, esp32, espressif-idf

I have troubles setting up GPIO wakeup from deepsleep the documentation seems very straightforward (https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v5.0/esp32c3/api-reference/system/sleep_modes.html). But I always get compilation error:

```
error: 'esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'esp_sleep_enable_bt_wakeup'?
   11 |     esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(WAKE_UP_GPIO, 0);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     esp_sleep_enable_bt_wakeup
```

my code is:

```
#define WAKE_UP_GPIO             GPIO_NUM_3
#include "esp_sleep.h"

void SleepControl::EnterInactiveMode()
{
    esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(WAKE_UP_GPIO, 0);
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
```

Did I forgot any macros, Inits or requires in the CMakeFile? Because of other components I use the ESP-IDF Framework so pls no Arduino answers.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Wakeup by ext0 and ext1 is not available for ESP32-C3, use `esp_deep_sleep_enable_gpio_wakeup()`, see my reply to another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76832730/4902099).